# Why CLR change meaning of my code?

Tags: .net, vb.net, clr, reverse-engineering, cil

We are working in project where we have done lots of versions (SVN) and many people working on it. Our client raised issue, which we have already fixed in code someday back. So I wanted to figure out, if we have sent correct build at client site. After checking lot many things, I found it is easiest to reverse code on Client side to see actual code. So I did it using Reflector.

VB.Net code,

```
Case RequestState.FirstComplete 'RequestState.FirstComplete = 2
Request.Time = Now

If ErrorCode = ProcessErrors.NONE OrElse ProcessErrors.SUBSCRIBER_BUSY_FOR_MT_SMS Then
'OrElse ErrorCode = ProcessErrors.EQUIPMENT_PROTOCOL_ERROR

NextStep(Id, GetDPC(id), NUMBER)
```

Reversed code,

```
case 2:
{
  request.Time = DateAndTime.Now;
  if (errorCode == 0)
  {

  }

  NextStep(invokeId, ref GetDPC(id), ref NUMBER);    
}
```

Now I am not able to understand this oversimplification. How come,

```
If ErrorCode = ProcessErrors.NONE OrElse ProcessErrors.SUBSCRIBER_BUSY_FOR_MT_SMS Then
```

Becomes,

```
if (errorCode == 0)
{
}
```

Comment: I guess `NONE` and `SUBSCRIBER_BUSY_FOR_MT_SMS` both having the number `0`.

Comment: No, NONE is 0 and SUBSCRIBER_BUSY_FOR_MT_SMS  is 31

Comment: That's not the CLR changing your code, it's the compiler. The CLR is the Common Language *Runtime*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because **your original code is incorrect**.

It should be

```
If ErrorCode = ProcessErrors.NONE OrElse ErrorCode = ProcessErrors.SUBSCRIBER_BUSY_FOR_MT_SMS Then
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can't use `OrElse` to test if some value (`ErrorCode`) is *one of two other values*.

Comment: Am no good in VB.net. Can you explain what does the OP's code mean then?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Neither am I. His code doesn't make sense, because (as I understand it) it's going to evaluate `ProcessErrors.SUBSCRIBER_BUSY_FOR_MT_SMS` as a boolean *by itself*, not checking for equality with `ErrorCode`. But, as it is non-zero, I would expect that to equate to `If ErrorCode = 0 OrElse True`, which would be `If True`. So I'm not sure.

Comment: `OrElse` is [equivalent to](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Articles/Logical%20Operator%20Equivalents%20in%20VB%20and%20CSharp.html) `||` in C languages.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I'm happy that such code won't compile in c#.